# how to suspend a remote process started by: local-shell -> ssh -> remote bash -> remote-process

Tags: bash, ssh, job-control

I have one, single terminal/channel to a remote system. I can use `ssh` to open Bash on that system and interact with it to invoke desired remote process. Due to some reason, the remote process is no longer responding. How can I suspend it to get back to the shell on the remote system? Typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> into the terminal suspends the `ssh` itself giving back the local shell.

In more details:

- The first step is to execute: `ssh -X user@host` in the local terminal. This gives access to an interactive shell on the remote system.
- Then a command is typed to run a shell script which is executing a few environment setting statements followed by invocation of an X11 binary. Once that binary gets into non-responsive state, I would like to regain access to the remote interactive shell. Unfortunately, typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> in the terminal suspends the `ssh` itself, giving access to the local shell...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show how exactly how you started this process. It sounds like you ran ssh on one host to invoke the command on another host? Please show the ssh command that you used. If the command is a shell script, show the contents of the script.

Comment: You can't do that at all unless you started ssh in a way that let it create a pseudo-tty on the remote system (no "command" argument, local input from a tty, `-t` or `-tt` options used)

Comment: I can't reproduce it: here (Arch Linux, OpenSSH, Bash), if the remote shell is started as `ssh -X user@host`, Ctrl+Z suspends the remote process and brings back the remote shell prompt—it doesn't suspend `ssh` on the local side. What operating systems and local shell are you using?

Comment: What does `alias ssh` (on the local machine) say? Does it help if you use the `-t` option: `ssh -X -t user@host`?